# How do I verify the .cssx file created with CSPack Azure SDK tool?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, deployment, azure, cloud

Once I use "Build->Publish->Create Service Package Only" to pack my Azure role I get two files. One is the .cscfg - a tiny XML file with service configuration. The other is the package itself which is in fact a ZIP archive with .cspkg extension.

The .cspkg file contains the .cssx file which grows larger and larger as I add stuff into my role. So I assume that the .cssx file contains all the contents of my role, binary files included. If I open it with a viewer - it doesn't contain any recognizable patterns, just some binary content.

I want to be sure that the package contains all the right stuff before I upload it to Windows Azure but since I can't analyze the .cssx file I can't do that. Is there a way to analyze the .cssx file to verify that it was assembled right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename the `[filename].cssx` file to `[filename].zip` and use and open the file using your prefered archiving utility.

Before you can do this you need to follow some steps to disable encrypting the archive.
More detailed info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2009/04/16/digging-in-to-the-windows-azure-service-package.aspx)

Comment: This answer is right, but starting with SDK 1.5 the archive is no longer encrypted, it's a plain ZIP and can be reviewed easily.